# How to split regex matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match all given `(` and `)` in a string, but I'm having trouble because of my current solution matches `()` while my intention is got a split result like `['(',')']`

My [`regex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) expression is: `/[()]+/g`, [Regex101 playground](https://regex101.com/r/Hjvw3c/1).

How can I manage to get the desired behavior **only with a regex** expression?

```js
const matchType = str => str.match(/[()]+/g)

console.log(matchType('{(})[]')); // ['(',')]

// Expected ['(',')']
console.log(matchType('{[()]}')); // ['()']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use quantifier `+`,

when you use `+` quantifier `+` it means one or more time,

`[()]+` this means match `( or )` one or more time, so when you have string like `()` it consider it as a single match

```js
const matchType = str => str.match(/[()]/g)

console.log(matchType('{(})[]')); // ['(',')]

// Expected ['(',')']
console.log(matchType('{[()]}'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get rid of the `+`:

```
const matchType = str => str.match(/[()]/g)
```

The `+` means that you will match on one or more parens.